# Is it possible to load a games quality with cycles before being played?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, game-engine

Would it be possible to use cycles to load a game if the games assets were loaded before the game was played? As an example, if I were to make a game where you sit in one place in a 3D room and all you can do is look around, could cycles render the room as a whole, to which I can look around smoothly as long as the room doesn't change? Or if the room were to change could it also render the animations with cycles completely before you play? If it takes cycles about a minute to load a frame, could a entire room rather than the frame be loaded with cycles? Because if the room isn't changing the shading and textures are staying in the same spot so how would a frame take a minute if you could just load the room first before and then allow you to move around the high quality room without reloading with each frame? To summarize I'm just asking if a game's models and animations could be preloaded with cycles rather than each frame have to be manually loaded for up to a minute.

Comment: the short answer is: no. Except you look around in a predefined matter and always only on that "path".

Comment: Cycles could be used to bake lighting. Then you pretty much have a Cycles render on your 3d model.